# What languages should I be good at to make an electron app?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, electron

I dived into this new subject Electron few months back. I'm a PHP developer, but after going through many articles on web I'm learning nodejs, express through online resources.

Could anyone here suggest me, what exactly I need to focus on. I'm really interested in making a Electron app with routing, CRUD, sessions etc.

Please suggest, your help will save me a lot of time

Comment: Erm... Javascript? Electron is Node+Chromium. You need to deal with server-side and client-side JS.

Comment: "Build cross platform desktop apps with JavaScript, HTML, and CSS" - from the Electron headline.

Answer (score 0):

Electron itself uses HTML, CSS, and JavaScript for the interface, with Node.JS for powering the background app stuff like opening windows, and keeping the app alive. For online interactivity, it can use any proper web server you want, be it PHP powered, an NGINX static site, or Express as you mentioned, or even use none at all - being a purely offline app.